# xml import into a mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, xml

i need help ... trying to import an xml file to mysql ...i would like to use php but anything would help

my xml file

```
<? xml version = '1.0' ?> < !DOCTYPE OffloadReport > < BIT_Report > < FlightLegInfo FlightLegId = "CLP01175:0497"
FlightNumber = "MAINT"
DepartureAirport = "LHR"
ArrivalAirport = "----"
FlightLegStartTime = "2014-03-19 19:07:02"
FlightLegStopTime = "2014-03-19 19:54:02"
AircraftTailSign = ".A4O-DD" >
```

the output

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<!DOCTYPE OffloadReport>
<BIT_Report>
  <FlightLegInfo FlightLegId="CLP01175:0497" FlightNumber="MAINT" DepartureAirport="LHR" ArrivalAirport="----" FlightLegStartTime="2014-03-19 19:07:02" FlightLegStopTime="2014-03-19 19:54:02" AircraftTailSign=".A4O-DD"></FlightLegInfo>
  <Equipment Hostname="A429_CMC">
    <EquipmentDetails>
      <StaticInfo LruType="100" LruSubType="28" hwPartNumber="" serialNumber="" macAddress="" ipAddress="" model="" revision="">
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried thus far? What issues have you encountered?

Comment: Your xml file isn't XML

Comment: Most likely it's incomplete. To import XML into a mysql database, please take a look into the mysql manual, it has a lot of material about that. you don't need to write software for it, it already exists.